# Display a popup on save of Account

Tags: popup

Once account is edited or saved, I need to show an alert message to the user to enter Team Entry record(Custom object that needs to be filled after any account/opportunity is updated or newly enetered)
Is there an easy way to show the popup? may be using javascript when the account is saved to remind the user to enter team entry?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can use Javascript to override / add events to the standard record form. Unfortunately, Aside from overriding a record edit form with a custom VF page or lightning component (Salesforce recommended way) I dont believe there is a clean way of doing this. I have reached this question several times and do not know the optimal way of implementing these types of requirements.

First thing that comes to mind is [overriding the Standard Save](https://www.salesforcetutorial.com/overriding-standard-new-button-vf-page/#:%7E:text=Steps%20to%20overriding%20standard%20buttons,above%20and%20save%20your%20changes.) button for the Account. (I have researched this and still do not know if this is possible in Classic or even Lightning), but you can look into that.

From a Salesforce point-of-view I think you can use the following:

1. Screen flow (using LWC or standard components) to create an Account and have the following screen prompt the user to create the Team Entry.
2. You can add dynamically standard lightning component to the Account Record Page (i.e, Related Record, Related List Flow) so that the users can easily and intuitively create a Team Entry record after updating an Account. Maybe you can display some large red text when an Account is missing a Team Entry to inform the user to do one. Depending on why you **require** a team entry record, you can equally throw an error in Apex or validation rule later on when the system requires one to ensure the user creates one before your business process completes.
3. Completely [Override the Account Edit Page with a LWC](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_tabs.htm). Gives you ultimate freedom and you can even force user to enter both the Account and Team Entry record on the same 'submit'. Obviously this approach takes additional maintenance and custom development.
4. You can use a workflow rule / trigger to email the user to remind user to create a Team Entry record following

These are several ideas that you will need to assess feasibility for each and if that aligns with your business or requirements. There are several other ways to accomplish this, but I am afraid there is not a direct way to **easily and optimally** accomplish what you are trying to do.

Good luck and please follow up on what you ended up doing!